# How can i select a song from a list using pygame.mixer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

How can i select a certain song to play it by using pygame? I put them into  a list, but the following codes are not working. When i run the app, it prints "none" and when i uncomment pygame.mixer.music.play, the app gives that error: "an integer required. Also when i change the codes as;

```
    selected_song = random.randint(0,len(songs))
    pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[selected_song])
```

It gives this error: Couldn't read from RWops. So i could not figure it out.

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame, os, random
pygame.mixer.init()
songs = (pygame.mixer.music.load("A.mp3"),
     pygame.mixer.music.load("B.mp3"),
     pygame.mixer.music.load("C.mp3"),
     pygame.mixer.music.load("D.mp3"))
window=Tk()
window.geometry("175x150")
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def play(init):
    selected_song = random.choice(songs)
    #pygame.mixer.music.play(selected_song) #uncomment this
    print(selected_song) #comment this
    return selected_song

a = Player()
l1=Label(window,text="Music Player",font="times 20")
l1.grid(row=1,column=1)

b1=Button(window,text="Play",width=20,command=a.play)
b1.grid(row=4,column=1)
#b2=Button(window,text="Pause",width=20,command=stop)

    #song_list=os.listdir()
    #song_listbox=StringVar(window)
    #song_listbox.set("select songs")
    #menu=OptionMenu(window,song_listbox,*song_list)
    #menu.grid(row=4,column=4)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.mixer.music.load()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) will always return `None`, hence your `songs` tuple will always be `(None, None, None, None)`:

> `pygame.mixer.music.load()`
>
> *Load a music file for playback*
>
> `load(filename) -> None`
> `load(object) -> None>`
>
> This will load a music filename/file object and prepare it for playback. If a music stream is already playing it will be stopped. This does not start the music playing.

It's always advantageous if not necessary to read the documentation of the libraries you use.

---

You should only store the filenames in `songs`:

```
songs = ("A.mp3", "B.mp3", "C.mp3", "D.mp3")
```

and to play a random music file, do

```
...
selected_song = random.choice(songs)   # select music file
pygame.mixer.music.load(selected_song) # load music file
pygame.mixer.music.play()              # play it
...
```

Note that this will only work if the music files are in the same directory where you start your program.

Comment: Thank you so much!! the problem was just about the names. The importance of reading the documentation before using the library.